# Why is this javascript function call not working?

Tags: javascript, function

Calling my function yields a syntax error, everything else works on its own. The error is thrown on.

```
console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Any ideas?

```html
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34)
{
 computerChoice = "rock";
} 
else if(computerChoice <= 0.67)
{
 computerChoice = "paper";
} 
else 
{
 computerChoice = "scissors";
}


var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
        {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper")
    {
     
      if (choice2 === "rock")
        {
            return "paper wins"
        }
        else
        {
            return "scissors wins"
        }
        
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors")
    {
        if (choice2 === "paper"
        {
            return "paper wins"
        }
        else
        {
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    }
}

console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Comment: `if (choice2 === "paper" ` -- missing the closing `)` after the `if` condition expression

Comment: Ooooppss added the error thanks man

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger.

Comment: use tools such as `jshint` to find those bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you forgot the `)` at `if (choice2 === "paper"`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, one of your closing `)`s was missing.

With lots of nested `if`-`else` blocks, it's easy to lose track of your `()`s and `{}`s. You can write much shorter, nicer, easier to read code if you utilise other conditional statements and expressions, namely the `switch` statement and the `?` operator:

```
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return 'The result is a tie';
    }

    switch(choice1) {
        case 'rock':
            return choice2 === 'scissors' ? 'rock wins' : 'paper wins';
        case 'paper':
            return choice2 === 'rock' ? 'paper wins' : 'scissors win';
        case 'scissors':
            return choice2 === 'paper' ? 'scissors win' : 'rock wins';
    }
}
```

As you can see, this code has much fewer `()`s and `{}`s.